# Как настроить различные конфигурации ресурсов для Debug/Realease в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, maven, wildfly

Имеется проект под сервер WildFly размещённый на OpenShift. Для тех, кто не знает, проекты на OpenShift публицируются по Git, и с помощью POM.xml собираются прямо на сервере.

Непосредственно вопрос. Для работы приложения на моём локальном и на удалённом сервере используются разные конфигурации приложения (хост/порт подключения к БД, которые хранятся в `.properties` файле).

Пусть Release файл конфигурации содержит данные для работы на конечном сервере, передаётся по Git и код ссылается именно на него. А Debug-файл содержит данные для развёртывания на локальном сервере и находится в отдельной папке ресурсов, не добавленной в Git.

Есть ли способ подмены основного Release файла на Debug файл, в зависимости от места запуска, используя средства IDEA, Maven или самой Java?

[image: Пример структуры проекта]

Comment: У вас проект под Git. Можно (и нужно) держать разработку и релиз в разных ветках и просто не мерджить конфигурационные файлы. [Примерно как тут описано](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b#.wxyosp4u7).

Comment: @enzo Хм, неплохая идея, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Проект более maven чем idea. Вам сюда http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html